# changing the Input name attribute in a jquery datatable cell

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, datatables

I am building a laravel app where i have a jquery datatable filled with some ajax data and has some input forms. The table columns are generated by the datatable column option. the problem is when i post the data it only gets the last row, because the name of every input is the same. i tried to change the name attribute using the jquery .attr() and .prop() but it didn't work. any help is appreciated.

PS: if you know any other way of passing data from a table to the database in laravel let me know.

Edit 1

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( "tr" ).each(function(index) {
        $("#id").attr('name',function(){
            return "text"+index;
        });
     });
});
```

Edit 2

```
var table = $('#monthly_table').DataTable({
        "paging": true,
        "dom": "fr<'clear'>Ttip",
        "ajax": "../ajax/data/objects.txt",
        "tableTools": {/*buttons */},
        "columns": [

            { "data": "kpi" },
            { "data": "workload" },
            {
                "className": '',
                "orderable": false,
                "defaultContent": '<input  class="form-control month" type="month" />'
            },
            {
                "className": '',
                "orderable": false,
                "defaultContent": '<input id="value"  class="form-control" type="number" />'
            },
            {
                "className": '',
                "orderable": false,
                "defaultContent": '<input id="comment" class="form-control" type="text" />'
            },
            {
                "className": 'details-control',
                "orderable": false,
                "defaultContent": '<a href="#" class="fa fa-info-circle"/>'
            },
            {
                "className": 'details-controlss',
                "orderable": false,
                "defaultContent": '<a href="#" class="fa fa-area-chart"/>'
            },
            {
                "className": 'details-controls',
                "orderable": false,
                "defaultContent": '<a href="#" class="fa fa-table"/>'
            }
        ],
        "order": [[1, 'asc']]
    });
```

Comment: Can you provide some code of how you've tried to solve the problem?

Comment: Are the inputs part of the dom on doc ready? Or are they added via ajax? If by ajax, you need to run that function in the ajax callback... Also, according to that code snippet, all of them have the same ID. You need to fix that first.

Comment: Just removed my answer, as now I see I'm not sure what element has the name on it...is it a `<td>` within the `<tr>` or the `<tr>` its self?

Comment: Is this question for the JQuery Datatables plugin? If so it should be re-tagged as `datatables`.

Comment: it's a <td> i tried your solution in the rowCreated callback but nothing changed.

Comment: @haakym yeap it is datatables.. sorry i missed the s

Comment: Can you show us the js which is responsible for instantiating datatables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the `createdRow` callback to update the data on each row. Also, your inputs did not have names on them, so I added the default name (and removed the ids), which will be updated in the `createdRow` callback:

```
var table = $('#monthly_table').DataTable({
    "paging": true,
    "dom": "fr<'clear'>Ttip",
    "ajax": "../ajax/data/objects.txt",
    "tableTools": {/*buttons */},
    "columns": [
        { "data": "kpi" },
        { "data": "workload" },
        {
            "className": '',
            "orderable": false,
            "defaultContent": '<input name="month" class="form-control month" type="month" />'
        },
        {
            "className": '',
            "orderable": false,
            "defaultContent": '<input name="value" class="form-control" type="number" />'
        },
        {
            "className": '',
            "orderable": false,
            "defaultContent": '<input name="comment" class="form-control" type="text" />'
        },
        {
            "className": 'details-control',
            "orderable": false,
            "defaultContent": '<a href="#" class="fa fa-info-circle"/>'
        },
        {
            "className": 'details-controlss',
            "orderable": false,
            "defaultContent": '<a href="#" class="fa fa-area-chart"/>'
        },
        {
            "className": 'details-controls',
            "orderable": false,
            "defaultContent": '<a href="#" class="fa fa-table"/>'
        }
    ],
    "order": [[1, 'asc']],
    "createdRow": function(row, data, dataIndex) {
        $(row).find('input').each(index, element) {
            var $element = $(element);
            $element.attr('name', $element.attr('name') + '-' + dataIndex);  
        }
    }
});
```

Another option would be to use a function with the `data` key, instead of `defaultContent`. Then you don't need the callback to update the names, as they are generated with the row index already.

```
var table = $('#monthly_table').DataTable({
    "paging": true,
    "dom": "fr<'clear'>Ttip",
    "ajax": "../ajax/data/objects.txt",
    "tableTools": {/*buttons */},
    "columns": [
        { "data": "kpi" },
        { "data": "workload" },
        {
            "className": '',
            "orderable": false,
            "data": function (row, type, val, meta) {
                return '<input name="month-' + meta.row + '" class="form-control month" type="month" />'
            }
        },
        {
            "className": '',
            "orderable": false,
            "data": function (row, type, val, meta) {
                return '<input name="value-' + meta.row + '" class="form-control" type="number" />'
            }
        },
        {
            "className": '',
            "orderable": false,
            "data": function (row, type, val, meta) {
                return '<input name="comment-' + meta.row + '" class="form-control" type="text" />'
            }
        },
        {
            "className": 'details-control',
            "orderable": false,
            "defaultContent": '<a href="#" class="fa fa-info-circle"/>'
        },
        {
            "className": 'details-controlss',
            "orderable": false,
            "defaultContent": '<a href="#" class="fa fa-area-chart"/>'
        },
        {
            "className": 'details-controls',
            "orderable": false,
            "defaultContent": '<a href="#" class="fa fa-table"/>'
        }
    ],
    "order": [[1, 'asc']]
});
```

And finally, your third option is to just make the names arrays. Now in your server side processing, your month, value, and comment inputs will be arrays with all the values in them.

```
var table = $('#monthly_table').DataTable({
    "paging": true,
    "dom": "fr<'clear'>Ttip",
    "ajax": "../ajax/data/objects.txt",
    "tableTools": {/*buttons */},
    "columns": [
        { "data": "kpi" },
        { "data": "workload" },
        {
            "className": '',
            "orderable": false,
            "defaultContent": '<input name="month[]" class="form-control month" type="month" />'
        },
        {
            "className": '',
            "orderable": false,
            "defaultContent": '<input name="value[]" class="form-control" type="number" />'
        },
        {
            "className": '',
            "orderable": false,
            "defaultContent": '<input name="comment[]" class="form-control" type="text" />'
        },
        {
            "className": 'details-control',
            "orderable": false,
            "defaultContent": '<a href="#" class="fa fa-info-circle"/>'
        },
        {
            "className": 'details-controlss',
            "orderable": false,
            "defaultContent": '<a href="#" class="fa fa-area-chart"/>'
        },
        {
            "className": 'details-controls',
            "orderable": false,
            "defaultContent": '<a href="#" class="fa fa-table"/>'
        }
    ],
    "order": [[1, 'asc']]
});
```

Comment: the 2nd method worked. thank you. however i want to tell you that the first method on the row created callback you are just adding the index to the elements of the row, so the output will be month-0, value-1, comment-2 in each row which leads to the same problem.

Comment: @xhulio Ah, a silly mistake on my part. `index` should have been `dataIndex`, which is the index of the row in the table. I have updated the code to reflect the change.

Comment: well you still gave the right answer so i appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

This will change (index) the name on all td's:

```
    $( "td" ).each(function(index, element) {
        var $ele = $(element),
            newName = $ele.attr('name')+index;
        $ele.attr('name',newName);
     });
```